# How to set HTTP status code on http.ResponseWriter

Tags: go

How do I set the HTTP status code on an `http.ResponseWriter` (e.g. to 500 or 403)?

I can see that requests normally have a status code of 200 attached to them.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Use [`http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#ResponseWriter). From the documentation:

> WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with status code. If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK). Thus explicit calls to WriteHeader are mainly used to send error codes.

Example:

```
func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    w.Write([]byte("500 - Something bad happened!"))
}
```

Comment: How can you access the header written in enclosing middleware.  res.Header().Get('StatusCode') gives nil.

Answer (score 132):

Apart from `WriteHeader(int)` you can use the helper method [http.Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error), for example:

```
func yourFuncHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    http.Error(w, "my own error message", http.StatusForbidden)

    // or using the default message error

    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
}
```

http.Error() and [http.StatusText()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StatusText) methods are your friends

Comment: I don't know why, but only this answer works for me, not "WriteHeader(int)", so thanx a lot!

Comment: Would you say its best practice to do http.Error over w.WriteHeader?

Answer (score 41):

```
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
```

full list [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants)

Comment: it logs `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call`

Comment: Hey @panchicore in case it wasn't obvious in hindsight - and for completion - you can only send one such header, the second was just a different example. The "superfluous" in that warning merely states that only the first should be sent.

Comment: @panchicore If `WriteHeader` is not called explicitly, the first call to `Write` will trigger an implicit `WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)`. Make sure you're calling `WriteHeader` before `Write`.